# multiprocessing.Pool inexplicably slow when passing around Pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pickle

I am trying to speed up a code path that creates Pandas data frames of some 100 mega bytes.

The obvious idea is to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. While the actual processing is parallelized as expected, it seems as if the IPC overhead makes things way slower than not doing any multiprocessing at all.

What really puzzles me is that I can work around the problem by pickling the frames to disk and loading them back once processing is finished. I expect that passing around things in-memory should be faster than using a hard disk.

Find a script below testing the two cases and for comparison plain bytes.

Manually dumping and loading is always way faster.

#### Measurements

Python 3.10 on Mac OS Ventura

```
Pandas frame: 56.739380359998904
Bytes: 100.31256382900756
Pandas hard disk: 2.5154516759794205
```

Python 3.10 on the same Mac but in a Docker container

```
Pandas frame: 30.639809517015237
Bytes: 17.284717564994935
Pandas hard disk: 4.386503675952554
```

#### Test script

My POC that simply dumps the frames to disk runs in **4 seconds**.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time


def creator(id_):
    # ~230 Mb in size
    return pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3000, 10000)))


def creator_bytes(id_):
    return bytearray(3000 * 10000 * 8)


def creator_pkl(id_):
    filename = f"pickled_{id_}.pkl"

    pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3000, 10000))).to_pickle(filename)

    return filename


if __name__ == "__main__":
    timestamp = time.perf_counter()

    fake_input = list(range(10))

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        results = p.map(creator, fake_input)

    print(f"Pandas frame: {time.perf_counter() - timestamp}")

    ###
    timestamp = time.perf_counter()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        results = p.map(creator_bytes, fake_input)

    print(f"Byte array: {time.perf_counter() - timestamp}")

    ###
    timestamp = time.perf_counter()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        results = p.map(creator_pkl, fake_input)

    print(f"Pandas hard disk: {time.perf_counter() - timestamp}")
```

Does anyone have an explanation of the overhead?

Comment: why are you not using an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard?

Comment: These snippets are no complete Python programs. Even with the guard, they would not work as the creator function cannot be pickled from the main script. It did not want to add the complexity of introducing a module to the question.

Comment: What are you talking about? if I add the guard it works fine (and the missing import). What do you mean "introducing a module"?

Comment: You understand that the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard is almost required for a multiprocessing program, correct? Otherwise, it can create a multiprocessing bomb. So, this oculdn't run on Windows or in any situation where you arent using forked processes. This is a basic thing you need to understand about multiprocessing.

Comment: No worries, I am aware of all the implication. Consider my initial code stripped down snippets. To see what I meant with "cannot be pickled" try to copy and paste into the reply. It won't work.

But I see you point - will rework the examples to complete scripts.

Comment: Anyway, on mac using the guard (so that the program can *actually run*) I can reproduce this discrepancy (1m39seconds vs 4 seconds). However,  I get a similar discrepency by just using `numpy`, although closer to 1 minute

Comment: **furthermore**, if I just use a `bytearray` object of similar size, so `bytearray(3000*10000*8)`, I get a little over a minute. So, this is probably not outside the realm of the overhead we would *expect*.

Comment: These both take roughly the same amount of time on my PC. The first one is slightly faster.

Comment: @TomMcLean Windows? What python version?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Windows, Python 3.8.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` documentation does not claim that it's providing something that is always going to provide more benefit than cost, and numpy and pandas go to a great deal of effort to perform locking so they can spin up threads running native code safely in large part so one doesn't _need_ hacks like multiprocessing when using them. Whether we're faster or slower than disk depends a great deal on active configuration; if "disk" isn't forced to be flushed to media, it can actually _be_ memory (in particular, OS block cache) in practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While there are a lot of cases where vectorization can outperform a lot of other approaches, it is no silver bullet, nevertheless.

Comment: I updated the script and added some more measurements.

Comment: That's really interesting, the new results. Can you tell us more about the container?

Comment: As plain as it can get. `docker run --rm  -ti python:3.10  /bin/bash` + `pip install pandas`

Comment: As a general aside: Creating a pool size of 1, submitting a task to the pool and then immediately blocking for the result (which is what the `map` method does) results in no real multiprocessing of any sort but you still incur the IPC overhead. In short, this could never perform better than serial processing.